# Django internationalization problems with fr-ca, es-us

Tags: python, django, internationalization

Working on internationalizing, *mainly the urls right now*, a site and everything seems to be working with the exception of Canadian French (fr-ca) and US Spanish (es-us).

I'm using Django 1.4

`settings.py` has `django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware` as an installed middleware

my list of language are:

```
ugettext = lambda s: s
LANGUAGES = (
    ('en',    ugettext('English')),
    ('en-gb', ugettext('English United Kingdom')),
    ('es',    ugettext('Spanish')),
    ('es-us', ugettext('Spanish United States')),
    ('fr',    ugettext('French')),
    ('fr-ca', ugettext('French Canada')),
)
```

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns

urlpatterns = patterns('myapp',
    (r'^example/?$',            'main.views.example'),
    (r'^$',                     'main.views.index'),

    (r'',                       include('myapp.main.urls')),
)

urlpatterns += i18n_patterns('myapp.main.views',  
    (r'^example/?$',            'example'),
    (r'^example_1/?$',          'example1'),
    (r'^example_2/?$',          'example2'),
    (r'^$',                     'index'),
)
```

I've run

```
# django-admin.py makemessages -l en
# django-admin.py makemessages -l en-GB
# django-admin.py makemessages -l fr
# django-admin.py makemessages -l fr_CA
# django-admin.py makemessages -l es
# django-admin.py makemessages -l es_US
#
# django-admin.py compilemessages
```

This is what I get:

```
|  Accept-Language Header              | Response Language  | Expected Language  |
|--------------------------------------|--------------------|--------------------|
|  fr-ca;q=0.9, fr;q=0.8               |       fr           |       fr-ca        |
|  fr-ca;q=0.9                         |       fr           |       fr-ca        |
|                                      |                    |                    |
|  es-us;q=0.9, es-mx;q=0.8, es;q=0.7  |       es           |       es-us        |
|  es-us;q=0.9                         |       es           |       es-us        |
|                                      |                    |                    |
|  en-gb;q=0.8, en-us;q=0.7, en;q=0.6  |       en-gb        |       en-gb        |
|  en-us;q=0.9                         |       en           |       en           |
|                                      |                    |                    |
|  fr-ca;q=0.8, en-gb;q=0.7            |       fr           |       fr-ca        |
|  fr-ca;q=0.7, en-gb;q=0.8            |       en-gb        |       en-gb        |
|--------------------------------------|--------------------|--------------------|
```

If I place the locale codes in the URL, then I get the correct locale response:

```
http://localhost:8000/fr-ca/       I get fr-ca text back
http://localhost:8000/fr/          I get fr text back
http://localhost:8000/en/          I get en text back
http://localhost:8000/en-gb/       I get en-gb text back
http://localhost:8000/es-us/       I get es-us text back
http://localhost:8000/es/          I get es text back
http://localhost:8000/             I get en text back _(Default in settings.py)_
```

en-gb works as expected, and in the last request is returned instead of the higher precedence fr-ca.

Am I just missing something, or do fr-ca/es-us just not work with Django?

---

(** I also sent in the default `django_language` cookie, and everything works as expected, so it looks like I'm only experiencing the issue when using the `Accept-Language` header. **)

---

**UPDATE** - *The short and sweet answer was already provided by @ilvar*

Awright, I finally dug down into Django source *(Since it's awesomely open source, and all)*

The file `[django/utils/translation/trans_real.py][1]` is where I found, verified, the answer.

Here's a snippet of the function `get_language_from_request`, line 350:

```
...
for path in all_locale_paths():
    if os.path.exists(os.path.join(path, dirname, 'LC_MESSAGES', 'django.mo')):
        _accepted[normalized] = lang
        return lang  
...
```

The `path` is set to the `conf/locale` directory of the Django install *(in site-packages)* and `dirname` is the locale name from the request, in my case `fr-ca`. So, if the Django install doesn't contain the locale from the request, which it doesn't have `fr-ca`, it will revert to one that is, `fr`.

Just above the snippet the language is checked for within the URL first, if you're using i18n routes, and then within the language cookie. If it exists in either then that language code is returned immediately, so it doesn't matter if the language doesn't exist within the Django install.

Handling it differently for 2/3 scenarios is what threw me off, but makes some sense since the browser could send anything, but if you've set a cookie|url then at that point it's your issue.

Thanks @ilvar for the answer, even though I questioned it ;)
**All I did was just copy the `fr` to `fr_CA`, within Django's locales, and voila...**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django fully [supports only](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/i18n/translation/#localization-how-to-create-language-files) locales which it is [shipped with](https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/django/conf/locale). But you can manually add necessary locales (copying them from `es` or `fr`, for example) in Django's library path.

Comment: We don't have the admin enabled for this site. All of our translations are created from scratch, so we don't need anything from the existing ones within the admin side. We have all of the translations working when using either the cookie and/or URL, just not with the `Accept-Language` when it's `fr-ca` or `es-us`. All of the others work as expected. So basically Django redirects to the appropriate URLs when the locale is set in the cookie, but not so with only the `Accept-Language` header.

Comment: I think it skips `Accept-Language` if that language code is not found in django's locale library.

Comment: You're right; I was just being stubborn in thinking that since it worked with URLs and Cookies that there must be something else going on. Thanks for your answer =)

Comment: Can you expand on this? What exactly do I need to do? Do I need to make symlinks in the Django module tree itself? I'd rather not do that; is there a way to do this within the confines of my own Django project?

Comment: It turns out that my language files (en_CA and fr_CA) are picked up fine as long as I have them in the `LANGUAGES` setting (as `en-ca` and `fr-ca`).